# pytest requires Python '>=3.5' but the running Python is 2.7.10

Tags: python, pip, pytest

I'm trying to install `pytest` using `pip` but running into this error:

```
pytest requires Python '>=3.5' but the running Python is 2.7.10
```

Pretty sure `pytest` is compatible with python 2. Any reason why I am not able to install it on my machine? As you can see in the error, I am running python 2.7.10 and do not have issue installing other packages.

Comment: You do know Python2 will no longer be supported in 2020 right? Also because of this, `pytest` says they will not support Python2 in newer versions. See [this](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/py27-py34-deprecation.html). If you want to use `pytest` you will need to manually install an old version (4.6 being the last to support python2). That being said I highly recommend to start porting to Python3.

Comment: https://python3statement.org/ Pytest is one of the packages participating.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I am aware of the fact but updating to python 3 is not an option for me at this time. So I need to figure out how to install it with the current version of python.

Comment: Better use `pip install "pytest<5"` than the accepted answer to get the latest version for Python 2.7.

Comment: @hoefling that makes sense, could you post it as a comment on the accepted answer or a new answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [changelog](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/changelog.html#pytest-4-6-0-2019-05-31):

> The 4.6.X series will be the last series to support Python 2 and Python 3.4.

Therefore, use

```
$ pip install "pytest<5"
```

to install the latest `pytest` version that supports Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fix that works for me:

pip install 'tornado<=5.1'

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the pytest [website](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/py27-py34-deprecation.html).

"The pytest 4.6 series will be the last to support Python 2.7 and 3.4, and is scheduled to be released by mid-2019. pytest 5.0 and onwards will support only Python 3.5+."

It's likely that a recent update to pytest now no longer supports your version of Python.

To install pytest 4.6 use the command:

```
pip install pytest==4.6
```

Answer (score -1):

Python 2 will be phased out by 2020. Several big packages (like NumPy and matplotlib) have already declared that they are no longer supporting Python 2. Several other packages, like this one, are following suit.

If you want to use this package, I would recommend switching to Python 3. There are already several tools, like [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) and [six](https://pypi.org/project/six/), to support this.